# Java parsing xml from url

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I need to create a application in java that can parse the xml doc (i write USD and i should get in return the rate for it)
http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml 
My Code right now looks like:

```
package bnr;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class Bnr {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    String url = "http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
    }
}
```

and its not working i get a parse error.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with it.
Thank you,

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? Btw. this code does not compile, since you have unhandled exceptions and you use a non-static variable in static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try your code .. it didn't compile because you use a non-static variable in static method, you need to declare url inside main

and to get your result you need to add transformer object

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String url="http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        System.out.println(output.trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to this this is a working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException  {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();



    }
```

Comment: Why is that a "solution"  "that can parse the xml doc" and avoid the "parse error"? You are not doing any XML parsing at all.